# Client-client conversation for same ms bot application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, botframework

Created simple ms bot application from [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart) example. If I connect to the bot with 2 different botframework-emulator applications they speaks with bot in different dialogs, do not see each other messages. I'd like to make bot app transparent: no bot messages, but all connected clients see each other messages - speaks in same "room".

How to organize this programmatically? Found some [Intermediator Bot sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) (C#), however it is a little bit complex: is there are something more simpler?

---

**Update:** Probably correct question will be the following: different clients (or botframework-emulators) connected to a bot app appear in different conversations, so they do not see each other messages. Question is how to connect all of them to same conversation?

Comment: What is your use case here?  Is there a reason a channel such as slack will not work for you?

Comment: @JasonSowers what is slack? My class should be called directly from a Windows Service, so it can't be integrated into Bot app. So need to establish connection: `Twillio Client<--> Bot application <--> My Client`, so message from twillio should go directly to my lib and vise versa. No messages from bot necessary here actually.

Comment: so basically the bot is created to forward messages between user(s) and channel(s)?

Comment: @kienct89 yes, between client and another client. Bot acts as a message router.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich I think you need to create the conversation between bot &  user programmatically (reference: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#conversation)

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich what is your "My client" channel? Where are all the messages that should be "in the same room" displayed?

Comment: @kienct89 that's helpful, thanks! Probably will place my client into dll and move back to bot application to simplify things and for convenience.